# What is the evaluaton order in simple List creation?

Tags: haskell

How is 1:(2:(3:[])) evaluated?

What rewriting steps are taken until we arrive to [1,2,3] ?

Is it

```
   1:(2:([3])
   1:([2,3])
   [1,2,3]
```

or something else? Is the above described way the only way? Or is there an other way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't anything for Haskell to actually evaluate here, since `:` is the constructor for lists.  When you write something like `[1, 2, 3]`, the compiler first de-sugars this to the form `1 : 2 : 3 : []`, and *this is its representation in memory*.  It'd be like asking what the evaluation order is for `Just 1`.  There isn't an evaluation order, because it's already in its "most evaluated" form, also known as normal form.

For lists, normal form is elements consed together in front of an empty list.  If it helps, you can think of lists defined as

```
data [a] = [] | a : [a]
```

Or alternatively

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
```

When you do pattern matching like

```
f (x:xs) = ...
```

This is equivalent to doing pattern matching like

```
f (Cons x xs) = ...
```

The only real difference is the names used.

---

So I guess the answer to your question is that you have the evaluation backwards, you don't go from `1:2:3:[]` to `[1, 2, 3]`, you go from `[1, 2, 3]` to `1:2:3:[]`, although this step occurs during de-sugaring.  As for list comprehensions, these get de-sugared into maps and filters using monadic functions like `>>` and `>>=`.  When you see something like `[1..10]`, this actually uses the `Enum` instance for its elements and gets de-sugared to `fromEnumTo` and similar functions.  All of these functions work with lists on the level of `:` and `[]`, so they're just working with the list type's constructors just as it would with any other data type.

---

As proof, if I had the code

```
module Foo where

x :: [Int]
x = [1, 2, 3]
```

And I compiled it with `ghc -c Foo.hs -ddump-ds`, I'd get

```
Foo.x :: [GHC.Types.Int]
[LclIdX]
Foo.x =
  GHC.Types.:
    @ GHC.Types.Int
    (GHC.Types.I# 1)
    (GHC.Types.:
       @ GHC.Types.Int
       (GHC.Types.I# 2)
       (GHC.Types.:
          @ GHC.Types.Int (GHC.Types.I# 3) (GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Types.Int)))
```

Which is has quite a lot of extra meta-data in there, so let's remove all the extra type annotations, module names, and other noise:

```
Foo.x :: [Int]
Foo.x = GHC.Types.: 1 (GHC.Types.: 2 (GHC.Types.: 3 []))
```

Or even more removed

```
x :: [Int]
x = : 1 (: 2 (: 3 []))
```

Note that in core (what GHC compiles Haskell source to, one of the 3 intermediate language used), we don't need parens around operators in prefix form.  But it's pretty easy to see that once everything is de-sugared it's simply represented as a list consed together.

But wait!  I thought [you said that the parens weren't needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853373/what-is-the-evaluaton-order-in-simple-list-creation/24853608?noredirect=1#comment38594205_24853608)?  That was true when it was in infix form, but now the `:` is being applied as a prefix function.  It's pretty easy to see that with prefix, the parens are needed, especially if you replace `:` with `Cons` and `[]` with `Empty`:

```
x = Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Empty))
```

Since the following wouldn't type-check.  It makes it look like `Cons` takes 6 arguments!

```
x = Cons 1 Cons 2 Cons 3 Empty
```

Comment: @Sibi Thanks!  But I don't think you should have deleted your answer, you should just edit it to include what happens when you have `let x = 1:2:3:[]`, then use `:sprint` on it.  That might help make it more clear to OP what's going on.

Comment: So 1:(2:(3:[])) is already the most evaluated form? The parenthesis don't matter ?

Comment: @jhegedus Yes, that is the most evaluated form and the parenthesis don't matter because of the fixity of `:`.  If you ask GHCi `:info (:)`, it'll tell you it has `infixr 5`, meaning it's right-associative.  Being right associative means that `1:(2:(3:[])) == 1:2:3:[]`, but `((1:2):3):[] /= 1:2:3:[]`.  Obviously, the second example wouldn't even type check.

Comment: I mean 1*2+3 is not the same as 1*(2+3)

Comment: @jhegedus No, but `(1+2)+3 == 1+(2+3)`.  Once you start mixing operators you have to keep other rules in mind, such as distributive laws and precedence.

Comment: Thank you! So `1:(2:(3:[]))` gets transformed into `1:2:3:[]` right away during compilation, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @jhegedus Correct, this occurs during the de-sugaring stage.  I'll add to my answer an actual dump from GHC's de-sugar stage.

Comment: I think "the language actually compiled by GHC" is a bit overstated, core is only the first of at least three intermediate languages GHC uses (the other GHC-specific ones being STG and C--), and last I heard GHC doesn't have a working parser to compile directly from it.